# pthread_create timing of writeback

Tags: c, pthreads, race-condition

In the call pthread_create(&id, NULL, &start_routine, arg), is the thread id guaranteed to be written to id before start_routine starts running?  The manpages are clear that the start_routine may but will not necessarily begin executing before the call to pthread_create returns, but they are silent on when the thread id gets written back to the passed thread argument.

My specific case is that I have a wrapper around pthread_create:

```
int mk_thread(pthread_t *id) {
  pthread_t tid;
  pthread_create(&tid,NULL,ThreadStart,NULL);
  if (id == NULL) {
    pthread_detach(tid);
  } else {
    *id=lid;
  }
}
```

which can obviously run the start routine before writing back.  I changed it to

```
int mk_thread(pthread_t *id) {
  pthread_t tid,tidPtr=id?id:&tid;
  pthread_create(tidPtr,NULL,ThreadStart,NULL);
  if (id == NULL) {
     pthread_detach(tid);
  }
}
```

This rewrite is much more stable in practice, but is it actually a fix or just a smaller window for the race condition?

Comment: Are you sure the second one is more stable?  I noticed a typo on line 2 where tidPtr should be a pointer while it's missing an asterisk.  Also, what's inside the variable "lid"?

Comment: I was lazy and typoed it in by hand.  The real code doesn't have those typos.  The "lid" in the first should be "tid", and yes the * is missing in the second.

Comment: Don't forget to check the return value of `pthread_create` to see if it succeeded or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thread id is definitely written before `pthread_create` returns. If you think about it, it would be impossible for `pthread_create` to work any other way. It could not delegate writing the thread id to the new thread, because the `pthread_t` variable might be out of scope by the time the new thread runs.

The relevant text is:

> Upon successful completion, pthread_create() shall store the ID of the created thread in the location referenced by thread.

(From http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_create.html) Note that it says "on successful completion" of the function, not "at an indeterminate time after successful completion".

The more interesting question, and I'm unclear on this one, is whether `pthread_create` must have finished writing the thread id to its destination before the new thread start function begins, i.e. whether the new thread can immediately see its own thread id, e.g. if it's to be stored in a global variable. I suspect the answer is no.

**Edit:** Upon rereading your question, it seems like you might really have been asking about this latter, more interesting question. In any case, there's no reason for the new thread's start function to use the thread-id written out by `pthread_create`. Your new thread can (and should) just use `pthread_self` to get its own thread id.

Comment: Isn't there pthread_self() to see a thread's own ID?  I think the problem lies somewhere else.

Comment: Race conditions are only possible between different threads, not within a single thread. So the question only makes sense, I believe, if OP is asking about whether the thread id will have been written in time for the new thread to see it. The problem is easily solved by having the new thread just use `pthread_self` to get its own thread id.

Comment: Yes, race condition is possible only on different threads or processes.  However, it's usually solved by locking mutexes and not tracking down the thread's ID.  But hey, we don't see the codes where race conditions occur, I think I'd better leave it for the time being.

Comment: pthread_self() doesn't help here, because it's not the new thread that needs to know its own id, it's any running thread that might check the global (yes, mutex-protected) list of running threads to know what threads can be joined.

Comment: Ah, I finally found a version of the reference with information on this particular item from [the open group](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_create.html).  The exact quote here is "There is no requirement on the implementation that the ID of the created thread be available before the newly created thread starts executing. "   which answers my "is it safe" question with a definite no.  So to be correct, my application needs to get the id differently (such as having the start routine immediately sleep and get signalled after the id is copied back)

Comment: d'oh, I just realized that that link I "discovered" is the same one you referenced.  I could have sworn I poked through all the manpages first.

Comment: Indeed now we've answered both questions.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that nothing in the spec requires pthread_create to assign its output parameter `pthread_t *thread` before code in `start_routine` begins to execute.

As a matter of practicality, the following program succeeds on many pthreads implementations (freebsd8 i386 and debian gnu/linux amd64) but fails on one of interest to me (debian/kfreebsd9 amd64):

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

pthread_t th;

void *asserter(void* unused) {
        pthread_t self = pthread_self(), th_=th;
        printf("th=%jd self=%jd\n", (intmax_t)th_, (intmax_t)self);
        assert(pthread_equal(th_, self));
}

int main() {
        int i;
        for(i=0; i<1000; i++) {
                pthread_create(&th, NULL, asserter, NULL);
                pthread_join(th, NULL);
        }
        return 0;
}
```

that said, I am not sure I understand how this detail of behavior is relevant to the two code alternatives you offer in the original question.  Though it occurs to me that if pthread_create writes other values to `*thread` during its execution, and you're using the value of `*id` in the other thread, it could be relevant.  The standard does not specify that no other 'intermediate' values are written to `*thread` during successful execution of pthread_create.